# Ubuntu 12.04: Starting Theme/Icon Manager from Terminal

Tags: 12.04, themes, icons

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 which is so far amazing.

Now I changed the background image and want to change the theme / icons as well.

In the gnome-control-center, there is no icon for changing the theme.

What must I enter to start the theme manager from shell / terminal - or what must I install to do so?

Yours, Joern

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Default Unity Desktop, you need to install Ubuntu Tweak via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa  
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Then run it from Dash or `super+A` , then under **`Tweaks`**  >>  **`Themes`** , you can change themes and icons . Including manually installed / Placed in ~/.themes directory as

[image]

Alternatively , another package  [**`My Unity`**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/myunity/) is also available to change Theme

[image]